# Using Perl, how do I decode or create those %-encodings on the web?

Tags: perl, url-encoding, percent-encoding

I need to handle URI (i.e. percent) encoding and decoding in my Perl script. How do I do that?

---

This is a question from the [official perlfaq](http://faq.perl.org). We're [importing the perlfaq to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/can-we-import-the-perlfaq-into-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 33):

This is the [official FAQ answer](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How_do_I_decode_or_c) minus subsequent edits.

Those `%` encodings handle reserved characters in URIs, as described in [RFC 2396, Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396). This encoding replaces the reserved character with the hexadecimal representation of the character's number from the US-ASCII table. For instance, a colon, `:`, becomes `%3A`.

In CGI scripts, you don't have to worry about decoding URIs if you are using [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI). You shouldn't have to process the URI yourself, either on the way in or the way out.

If you have to encode a string yourself, remember that you should never try to encode an already-composed URI. You need to escape the components separately then put them together. To encode a string, you can use the [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI::Escape) module. The `uri_escape` function returns the escaped string:

```
my $original = "Colon : Hash # Percent %";

my $escaped = uri_escape( $original );

print "$escaped\n"; # 'Colon%20%3A%20Hash%20%23%20Percent%20%25'
```

To decode the string, use the uri_unescape function:

```
my $unescaped = uri_unescape( $escaped );

print $unescaped; # back to original
```

If you wanted to do it yourself, you simply need to replace the reserved characters with their encodings. A global substitution is one way to do it:

```
# encode
$string =~ s/([^^A-Za-z0-9\-_.!~*'()])/ sprintf "%%%0x", ord $1 /eg;

#decode
$string =~ s/%([A-Fa-f\d]{2})/chr hex $1/eg;
```

Comment: Mark Stosberg has a relevant blog post: http://mark.stosberg.com/blog/2010/12/percent-encoding-uris-in-perl.html on the topic.

Comment: Here's a different use case for those who find themselves on this post while doing bash one-liner where you need to encode in a substitute  


`$ echo "Colon : Hash # Percent %" | perl -MURI::Escape -pe 's/.*/uri_escape($&)/e'`  

Output will look something likes this:  
 `Colon%20%3A%20Hash%20%23%20Percent%20%25`

Answer (score 5):

DIY encode (improving above version):

```
$string =~ s/([^^A-Za-z0-9\-_.!~*'()])/ sprintf "%%%02x", ord $1 /eg;
```

(note the '%02x' rather than only '%0x')

DIY decode (adding '+' -> ' '):

```
$string =~ s/\+/ /g; $string =~ s/%([A-Fa-f\d]{2})/chr hex $1/eg;
```

Coders helping coders - bartering knowledge!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help deciding which method to choose.

Benchmarks on perl 5.32. Every function returns same result for given `$input`.

Code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $input = "ala ma 0,5 litra 40%'owej vodki :)";

use Net::Curl::Easy;
my $easy = Net::Curl::Easy->new();
use URI::Encode qw( uri_encode );
use URI::Escape qw( uri_escape );
use Benchmark(cmpthese);

cmpthese(-3, {
    'a' => sub {
        my $string = $input;
        $string =~ s/([^^A-Za-z0-9\-_.!~*'()])/ sprintf "%%%0x", ord $1 /eg;
    },
    'b' => sub {
        my $string = $input;
        $string = $easy->escape( $string );
    },
    'c' => sub {
        my $string = $input;
        $string = uri_encode( $string, {encode_reserved => 1} ); 
    },
    'd' => sub {
        my $string = $input;
        $string = uri_escape( $string );
    },
});
```

And results:

```
       Rate      c      d      a      b
c    5618/s     --   -98%   -99%  -100%
d  270517/s  4716%     --   -31%   -80%
a  393480/s  6905%    45%     --   -71%
b 1354747/s 24016%   401%   244%     --
```

Not surprising. A specialized C solution is the fast. An in-place regex  with no sub calls is quite fast, followed closely by a copying regex with a sub call. I didn't look into why `uri_encode` was so much worse than `uri_escape`.

Answer (score -1):

`use URI` and it will make URLs that just work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted but a one liner example may be needed.
`$ perl -MURI -E 'my $u=URI->new("https://host:123/"); $u->query_form("foo/slash"=>"1 x", "bar:colon"=>2, foo=>3); say $u;'`
`https://host:123/?foo%2Fslash=1+x&bar%3Acolon=2&foo=3`

Comment: and the reverse 

`perl -MURI -E 'my $u=URI->new(q{https://host:123/?foo%2Fslash=1+x&bar%3Acolon=2&foo=3}); say join ", ", $u->query_form;'`
`foo/slash, 1 x, bar:colon, 2, foo, 3`